# Wait then execute code in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

Ok, i have a closing event on my form. The code inside it fades the form out, then opens the other form. Is there a way i can wait until the fade is done? Here is my code:

```
    private void form1_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Opacity > 0.01f)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            timer1.Interval = 47;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();

        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(+1);
        label4.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%"; 
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 100; 
            timer2.Stop();
            this.Close();
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.Show(); 
        }
    }
```

Basically, form2 is opening early, i want it to wait after the fade effect is done. :)

Comment: Are you saying that the form is closing too early?

Comment: You could simply set a global variable like `form1_faded = true` and check it in the second call.

Comment: Well, yes and no, the form is closing before the progressbar actually shows it is on 100. Also, form2 popups up before the fade out is done.

Comment: where is modified the Opacity ?

Comment: instead of using "this.Opacity" to know if you should fade, try using a class property i.e. "bool _canCloseForm" that you set to true once the progressBar reach 100%. Also try to open the Form2 in the form1_closing "else".

Comment: @Fabske i put it in the else, but form 2 did not open :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code should do, I guess.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        for (double i = 1.0; i > 0.0; i-=0.01)
        {
            this.Opacity = i;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

  //Handle whatever you want to do here. The control comes here only when the form is faded out.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
void Wait(int Milliseconds)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    while(sw.ElapsedMillisecods < Millisecods)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    sw.Stop();
}
```

Here is a `Wait` function and you can use it if you can calculate the total time taken during fading like this :

```
Wait(Time)
```